# Missing one space in python string format

Tags: python, string, file, format

Hello I am am trying to format string and somehow I am missing 1 space. I know it may look trivial and some people may say its just 1 space but I want to see what am I missing.

```
file_out=open("Check.log","w")
file_out.write("{0:12} {1:20} {2:30}\n".format("TUPLE","LOGFILE STATUS","FSDB STATUS"))
file_out.write("{:12} {:20}".format((tuple_id+number),"Clean"))
file_out.write("{:30}\n".format("FSDB missing"))
file_out.write("{:12} {:20} {:30}\n".format(tuple_id,"Missing","Not Applicable"))
```

Please see this is just partial code just to explain the problem. The complete output is as follows

```
TUPLE        LOGFILE STATUS       FSDB STATUS                   
1234567_2    Clean               FSDB missing                  
1234556      Clean               FSDBs dumped successfully     
1234567_5    Not Clean           FSDB missing                  
1234567_4    Not Clean           FSDB missing                  
1234567_1    Clean               FSDBs dumped successfully     
1234567      Missing              Not Applicable
```

I counted the spaces. In first line Starting from "T" to 2 spaces before "L" there are 12 spaces then 1 space then starts `LOGFILE STATUS` so in essence it gave placeholder for 12 characters then starts new word with 1 space. Same is true for `LOGFILE STATUS` and `FSDB STATUS` ie 20 spaces plus 1 space then it prints `FSDB STATUS` but As you can see rest of the lines there is just 20 spaces i.e between `Clean` and `FSDB missing` or the other table entries though I have same spacing for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
file_out.write("{:12} {:20} ".format((tuple_id + number), "Clean")) 
# _________________________^ you're missing this one
```

Needs a space at the end, to be consistent with the other lines. I assume that line is in a loop.

Comment: oh my god. Thank you so much. This small thing was driving me crazy and I  was thinking of end of string characters etc. Face palm moment. How can I miss this thing.

Comment: @AashishsharmaSharma A fresh perspective always helps. :)